# Generating downloadable reports with shiny in LAN

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, lan

I shared an Rshiny app in LAN with my coworkers PCs, so I used `shiny.host` and `shiny.port`

So when my coworkers in theirs PCs tried to download reports when clicking in a `report_button` button, they received the last values that I chose on my PC

example:
On my PC I choose `input$slider` = 46 and I download the report file in HTML, then my coworker on his PC opens the link 192.168.5.140:8888 in his browser, chooses `input$slider`=73 and downloads the file, and then (!!!) he gets the same report that I got, i.e he gets `input$slider` = 46

here is the code :

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.host = '192.168.5.140')
options(shiny.port = 8888)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
  downloadButton("report_button", "Generate report") 
)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$report_button<- downloadHandler(
        # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
     filename = "report.html",
     content = function(file) {
        # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
        # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
        # can happen when deployed).
     tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
     file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
    
        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
     params <- list(n = input$slider)
    
        # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
        # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
        # from the code in this app).
     rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                      params = params,
                      envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
         )
       }
     )
    }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and the report.RMD file :

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r}
 # The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to prevent this situation by using `tempfile` instead of `tempdir` to create the temporary `Rmd` file.

`tempdir` is constant as long as you are running the same R-session - which might end up in concurrent shiny sessions overwriting each others report results.

`tempfile` however, creates a unique file for each function call:

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.host = '0.0.0.0')
options(shiny.port = 8888)

ui = fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
  downloadButton("report_button", "Generate report") 
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  output$report_button<- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(n = input$slider)
      
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What if we need to copy both our `*.Rmd` and the `reference_docx:` to a `dir.create(tempfile())` ?

Comment: I guess you could use `dirname(tempReport)` or `fs::path_dir(tempReport)` and copy it to the same folder.

Comment: I see. I’m not facing the same issue as the post but curious if there was a solution when multiple files are called for rendering purposes. Thank you.