# Generate and download report in Shiny from a selected Rmd

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, reporting

I would like to use a Shiny app to generate and download an html report from selected data. The basic of this is explained on [the Shiny Posit website](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/generating-reports/).

The main difference with this example and similar questions is that I would like the user to upload both the .rmd file and the data used for the report (say, a .txt file with two columns called x and y and containing coordinates of points) so that the report is knitted from the uploaded files.

The reason for this desired behavior is that my app will be hosted on a server that is accessible from the web (to launch the app), but I do not want to allow external parties to have access to the .rmd template nor to the data. Therefore, uploading the data and .rmd temporary is (I think) sufficient to prevent unauthorized access.

My current app.r is as follows (but is not working due to a mess with temporary files paths):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyFiles)
library(magrittr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="App"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(box(
      #Data
      {fileInput(
        inputId="inputfile",
        label="Select .txt (tab delimited) :",
        multiple = FALSE,
        accept=".txt")},
      #Decimal separator
      selectInput(
        inputId="separator",
        label="Select decimal separator :",
        choices=c(
          "Comma"=",",
          "Dot"="."),
        selected="Dot"),
      #Rmd template
      {fileInput(
        inputId="templatefile",
        label="Select template (.rmd) :",
        multiple = FALSE,
        accept=".rmd")}
    )),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width=6,
        align="right",
        downloadButton(
          "report",
          "Generate report")))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), input$templatefile$datapath)
      file.copy(input$templatefile$datapath, tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(input$inputfile$datapath, tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      rmarkdown::render(
        input=tempReport,
        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()),
        params=list(
          inputfile=input$inputfile$datapath,
          separator=input$separator))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

A dummy .rmd could be:

````
---
title: "Dummy report"
output: html_document
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
params:
  inputfile:
    label: "Select input data"
    input: file
    value: "test.txt"
  separator:
    label: "Select decimal separator"
    input: select
    value: "."
    choices: [",", "."]
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  message=FALSE,
  warning=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r}
#Read data
inputdata<-read.table(
  file=params$inputfile,
  header=TRUE,
  sep="\t",      #tabulation
  dec=params$separator,
  fill = TRUE)

ggplot(
  data = inputdata,
  aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_point()
  
```
````

Comment: what the point of the first copy if its immediately invalidated by the second ? `file.copy(input$templatefile$datapath, tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy(input$inputfile$datapath, tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)`

Comment: Why don't you use e.g. [{shinymanager}](https://datastorm-open.github.io/shinymanager/) for authentication? Regarding the file paths, please find a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019108/generating-downloadable-reports-with-shiny-in-lan/71021014#71021014).

Comment: BTW, mandating that users upload the `.Rmd` file is not only a little risky in general, even a casual approach will likely give non-authorized users the ability to see all of your code, negating your attempt at obfuscating/hiding proprietary processes. The exception to this is if ***ALL*** proprietary code is contained within the `.Rmd` file, and the only thing your shiny app does is render it with their supplied data as its sole `params=` argument. In this case, you would likely be better off "teaching" (perhaps step-by-step instructions) how to run it in R directly (or cloud).

Comment: Thank you for your comments !

Indeed, the goal was to store all the proprietary code in the .Rmd so that the only task of shiny is to render the .Rmd without letting the users  mistakenly mess with the code in the .Rmd. In the end, I decided to try only offline to avoid using Shiny (even though I am sure it is a viable option)